# Symfony2 : Switching between app.php and app_dev.php, am I doing it right?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I'm currently setting up symfony2 on a remote server that we'll call www.domain.com.

I want all my user that call the address www.domain.com to be redirected to **www.domain.com/app.php**, so I wrote a RewriteRule, and it's working fine.

Now I still want our developers to access the app_dev.php on the domain www.domain.com, so I created the following subdomain : **www.dev.domain.com** that has a specific RewriteRule to redirect to app_dev.php

My setup is working fine, but it look like kind of hacky so I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve that ?

Here's my RewriteRules :

```
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain.com|www.domain.com)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.dev.domain.com|dev.domain.com)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks !

Comment: Looks good to me, just remember to secure dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it sound a little bit tricky but it's fine. 
Another thing is: If you've created a subdomain (dev.domain.com), why don't you do this subdomain be an entirely project for developers? 
I mean, doing the trick with .htaccess if the developers make changes to the code these changes will be directly done also in production. 
If you've 2 projects with one in production (domain.com with the app.php) and another for development (dev.domain.com with app_dev.php) the developers will have the possibility to develop freely without worrying for the consequences on production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback, It's actually what I wanted to have the exact same code in dev.xxx.com and xxx.com as we already have a local dev environment, but that would be an interesting set up as well !

Comment: You're welcome. I've this exactly setup in my projects and it's really easy and useful to work with it.